# Simple Question About Contour Integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

If you are integrating $$\int_\gamma y^2\,dz$$ Where $\gamma$ is the line segment from $1$ to $i$. You parameterize the line $$x(t)=1-t$$ $$y(t)=t$$ $$\implies z(t)=1-t+it$$

Now, if you want to use the formula: $$\int_\gamma f(z(t))z'(t)\,dt,$$ would you have the integral $$\int_0^1(t)^2(-1+i)\,dt$$ or would you have $$\int_0^1(it)^2(-1+i)\,dt.$$ I'm assuming its the first integral because you want the imaginary part, which is just $t$ and not $it$.

Comment: What is your $f$? $f(z) = ?$

Comment: How do you get that parametrization? I assume x and y are the real and imaginary parts respectively? Because if so, there should be no x.

Comment: Also, why do you only want the imaginary part in your integral? $f(z(t))$ means what it says: take $f$ of the whole complex number $z(t)$

Comment: In Frumpy's case, $f(z) = \text{Im}(z)^2$. So $f(z(t)) = \text{Im}(z(t))^2 = t^2$.

Comment: Oh, I misread that as $\int_\gamma z^2 dz$

Comment: Where's the $x$
$$\begin{gathered}
  z = iy,\overline z  =  - iy,dz = idy \hfill \\
  z\overline z  = {y^2} \hfill \\
  z\overline z dz = {y^2}idy \hfill \\
  \int\limits_\gamma  {z\overline z  \cdot dz = } \int\limits_\gamma  {{y^2}idy}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the first one: $\int_0^1 t^2(-1 + i)\, dt$. The choice of $f(z)$ is $f(z) = \text{Im}(z)^2$. So with $z(t) = (1 - t) + it$, we have $z'(t) = -1 + i$ and thus

$$\int_\gamma y^2\, dz = \int_0^1 f(z(t))z'(t)\, dt = \int_0^1 t^2(-1 + i)\, dt = \frac{-1 + i}{3}.$$

Comment: I used the formula for parametrization, and I got $z(t)=1-t+it$

Comment: You parametrized the line segment from $1$ to $i$, not from $0$ to $i$.

Comment: My fault Kobe, I meant 1 to $i$.

Comment: I've made changes according to your edit.